# Combine 2 arrays

Tags: php, mysql

I have 2 separate arrays being pulled from MYSQL database, and want to combine both arrays on the key, so I can use a php foreach statement.

*I tried doing 1 query with both, but could not figure out how to get my foreach $video[0] to work.*

match_descr = video code

m_date = date

SQL

```
    $query = "SELECT match_descr FROM  #__bl_match  WHERE match_descr != '' ORDER BY m_date DESC";
    $db->setQuery($query);
    $videomatch = $db->loadResultArray();

     $query = "SELECT m_date FROM  #__bl_match  WHERE match_descr != '' ORDER BY m_date DESC";
    $db->setQuery($query);
    $videomatch2 = $db->loadResultArray();
```

PHP

```
$video = $this->videomatch;

for ($i=1;$i<=1;$i++){
echo '<div id="videoFrame" align="left"><iframe name="videoFrame" title="YouTube video     
player" width="560" height="315"    src="http://www.youtube.com/embed/' . $video[0] . '" frameborder="0"     allowfullscreen=""></iframe></div>';
  echo '<br />';

 echo '<br />';
 echo '<div id="videoThumbnails" align="left">'; 
 echo '<table>';
foreach ($video as $value)
 {

  echo '<tr>';
  echo '<td>';
 echo '<a href="http://www.youtube.com/embed/' . $value . '" target="videoFrame"><img height="75px" width="123px" src="http://img.youtube.com/vi/' . $value. '/2.jpg" alt="' .     $value . '" />    </a>';
echo '</td>';
echo '<td>';
echo (THIS IS WHERE I WOULD LIKE TO PUT THIS VIDEOS DATE);
echo '<br />';
echo 'California';
echo '<br />';
echo '1-19-2012';
echo '</td>';
echo '</tr>';

}
echo '</div>';}
```

Comment: Is there a reason you aren't selecting both columns in the initial query? why 2 separate queries on the same table?

Comment: What happened to `SELECT match_descr, m_date FROM  #__bl_match  WHERE match_descr != '' ORDER BY m_date DESC` ?

Comment: When I select Both, the foreach statement doesnt work, Not sure how to rewrite it

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You are (usually) better off selecting both rows in the same query:

```
SELECT match_descr, m_date FROM  #__bl_match  WHERE match_descr != '' ORDER BY m_date DESC
```

It appears that you are using Joomla. If this is the case, I don't think you can use `loadResultArray()` to iterate multiple columns (you can give it an index to get one of the columns, but that's not helpful in this case). Instead, you can use `loadRowList` to get an index array of the columns, or `loadAssocList` to get an associative array of the columns.

They can be used as follows (without all the html for brevity):

loadRowList:

```
$query = "SELECT match_descr, m_date FROM  #__bl_match  WHERE match_descr != '' ORDER BY m_date DESC";
$db->setQuery($query);
$videomatch = $db->loadRowList();

foreach ($videomatch as $row) {
    echo "{$row[0]} ({$row[1]})\n";
}
```

loadAssocList:

```
$query = "SELECT match_descr, m_date FROM  #__bl_match  WHERE match_descr != '' ORDER BY m_date DESC";
$db->setQuery($query);
$videomatch = $db->loadAssocList();

foreach ($videomatch as $row) {
    echo "{$row['match_desc']} ({$row['m_date']})\n";
}
```

Reference: http://docs.joomla.org/How_to_use_the_database_classes_in_your_script

Comment: Yes I am using Joomla. LoadAssocList worked great! Thank you!

Answer (score 0):

I would like to suggest you following.

```
$query = "SELECT match_descr, m_date FROM  #__bl_match  WHERE match_descr != '' ORDER BY m_date DESC";
$db->setQuery($query);
$videomatch = $db->loadResultArray();
```

Your following loop only work one time. So I think you do not need a for loop here.

```
for ($i=1;$i<=1;$i++){
```

And you can change your foreach loop as bellow and use it

```
foreach ($videomatch as $video)
 {
    $videoCode = $video['match_descr'];
    $date = $video['m_date'];
}
```

Please try. And if you want to work with  `$video[0]` as you mentioned. Use it as  `$video[0]['match_descr']` .

Comment: I forgot to mention that I am using Joomla, and I guess that is why LoadResultArray wasnt working with multiple variables. Thank you for your answer, I am sure it would have worked great otherwise!